# Exception in Native part of openejb

Tags: java, jpa, openjpa, openejb

I start a new topic for my problem, as I mentioned some wrong things in an older one.

I'm using openejb for writing integration tests for my beans using jpa. Currently I've an Exception in some native calls done by jpa:

```
INFO - Creating subclass and redefining methods for "[class ContextKey, class ContextEntity]". This means that your application will be less efficient than it would if you ran the OpenJPA enhancer.
SEVERE - EjbTransactionUtil.handleSystemException: null
<openjpa-2.3.0-nonfinal-1540826-r422266:1542644 fatal general error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceException: null
    at org.apache.openjpa.enhance.ClassRedefiner.redefineClasses(ClassRedefiner.java:96)
    at org.apache.openjpa.enhance.ManagedClassSubclasser.prepareUnenhancedClasses(ManagedClassSubclasser.java:176)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.AbstractBrokerFactory.loadPersistentTypes(AbstractBrokerFactory.java:312)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.AbstractBrokerFactory.initializeBroker(AbstractBrokerFactory.java:236)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.AbstractBrokerFactory.newBroker(AbstractBrokerFactory.java:212)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.DelegatingBrokerFactory.newBroker(DelegatingBrokerFactory.java:155)
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:226)
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:59)
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.ReloadableEntityManagerFactory.createEntityManager(ReloadableEntityManagerFactory.java:159)
    at org.apache.openejb.persistence.JtaEntityManagerRegistry.getEntityManager(JtaEntityManagerRegistry.java:115)
    at org.apache.openejb.persistence.JtaEntityManager.getEntityManager(JtaEntityManager.java:91)
    at org.apache.openejb.persistence.JtaEntityManager.persist(JtaEntityManager.java:137)
    at com.six.ao.atm.database.context.AtmContextBean.persistWithCommit(AtmContextBean.java:24)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext$Invocation.invoke(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:182)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext.proceed(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:164)
    at org.apache.openejb.monitoring.StatsInterceptor.record(StatsInterceptor.java:180)
    at org.apache.openejb.monitoring.StatsInterceptor.invoke(StatsInterceptor.java:99)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext$Invocation.invoke(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:182)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext.proceed(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:164)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.InterceptorStack.invoke(InterceptorStack.java:80)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.stateless.StatelessContainer._invoke(StatelessContainer.java:212)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.stateless.StatelessContainer.invoke(StatelessContainer.java:181)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.EjbObjectProxyHandler.synchronizedBusinessMethod(EjbObjectProxyHandler.java:268)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.EjbObjectProxyHandler.businessMethod(EjbObjectProxyHandler.java:263)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.EjbObjectProxyHandler._invoke(EjbObjectProxyHandler.java:86)
    at org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.BaseEjbProxyHandler.invoke(BaseEjbProxyHandler.java:303)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy68.persistWithCommit(Unknown Source)
    at com.six.ao.atm.database.context.AtmContextBeanIT.persistWithCommit_readAfter_sameObject(AtmContextBeanIT.java:43)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.openjpa.enhance.ClassRedefiner.redefineClasses(ClassRedefiner.java:85)
    ... 60 more
Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError
    at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.retransformClasses0(Native Method)
    at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.retransformClasses(InstrumentationImpl.java:144)
    ... 65 more
```

First I thought my classes are not enhanced, but as the first line mentions, the classes are subclasses, as I'm don't using the java agent to do the enhancing.

Here is my persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence ...>
  <persistence-unit name="atm">
    <jta-data-source>java:/atmAoDS</jta-data-source>
    <properties>
        <property name="showSql" value="false"/>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect" /> 
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Any Idea?

Comment: What version of Java are you using?

Comment: Java 1.7 (Version 51)

Comment: and the contents of your persistence.xml file?

Comment: I added my persistence.xml to the question. I tried with a specific persistence.xml for my tests, but then I've an exception that my Unit is defined twice.

Comment: As I mentioned in your other posting, don't use RuntimeUnenhancedClasses.

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same error while testing my code using OpenEJB.
Actually, what is important is the final piece of your exception trace.

```
Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError
at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.retransformClasses0(Native Method)
at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.retransformClasses(InstrumentationImpl.java:144)
```

The solution could be found in the last answer here by Dominik [java.lang.VerifyError: Expecting a stackmap frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8958267/java-lang-verifyerror-expecting-a-stackmap-frame). Just set -XX:-UseSplitVerifier.

PS: Tried to use Enhancement as mentioned here [Is a method in a JPA entity allowed to throw an Exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14708516/is-a-method-in-a-jpa-entity-allowed-to-throw-an-exception) by Rick and here http://openjpa.208410.n2.nabble.com/Fwd-org-apache-openjpa-persistence-PersistenceException-null-td7584865.html but faced a couple of hurdles. The first was overcame by the recipe above, but the second is arguably a bug https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/OPENJPA-1879 when using enhancement with Eclipse.

The trace reads like this.

```
<openjpa-2.3.0-nonfinal-1540826-r422266:1542644 nonfatal user error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.InvalidStateException: Primary key field YOUR_CLASS.id of YOUR_CLASS@755629fd has non-default value. The instance life cycle is in PNewState state and hence an existing non-default value for the identity field is not permitted. You either need to remove the @GeneratedValue annotation or modify the code to remove the initializer processing.
```